# Python Pandas - Read data rows and non text in quotes from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having issue trying to read csv file with pandas as the data are within quotes and whitespaces are present.

The header row in csv file is "Serial No,First Name,Last Name,Country".

Example data of each row is "1    ,""David, T    "",""Barnes  "",""USA  """.

Below is the code I have tried thus far trying to remove the quotes and reading the text that are within 2 quotes.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=',', encoding='ansi', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, doublequote=True, engine="python")
```

Is there a way to pre-process the file so that the result is as follows?

```
Serial No, First Name, Last Name, Country

1, David,T, Barnes, USA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('sample.txt',sep=',\s+',skipinitialspace=True,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,engine=python)
```

Comment: I just realised that some data in the "first name" column contains commas and hence was interpreted as a separator, any ways to leave the commas within the column as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this as I am using editpad to replace the commas and removing quotes as a walk-around.